# Form elements in flexbox not fixed as I slide the input range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

As the title suggests, I am making a Simple Interest Calculator. The rate is put in by the user using input range slider. But when I slide, all the form elements adjust themselves with it. I am unable to understand how to correct this. I used flexbox for the first time in the css part of this. And I know the problem lies there. Please help. Here is the code:

```css
.maindiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 480px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Please note that the maindiv is a class inside which I have placed the form elements and the form looks like this

[image: This is the link here]

Answer (score 0):

Give the input tag that has the range an id then you style it separately.